# Java RegEx split after every third whitespace

Tags: java, regex

Let´s say I have the String `"a 1 b c 2 3 d e f 4 5 6"` and I would like to split it on every third whitespace to get the substrings `"a 1 b"`, `" c 2 3"`, `" d e f"`, and so on. How would I do that usuing Regular Exprssions? I have tried different variants of `"(?=[\\w+][\\s+][\\w+][\\s+][\\w+][\\s+])"` none of which seem to be right. What would be the correct RegEx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a pattern matcher with the regex pattern:

```regex
\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,2}
```

This will match each term in the input according to your definition:

```regex
\S+    match first "word"
(?:
    \s+  whitespace
    \S+  another word
){0,2}   zero to two times
```

```java
String input = "a 1 b c 2 3 d e f 4 5 ";
String pattern = "\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){0,2}";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(0));
}

System.out.println(matches);
```

This prints:

```
[a 1 b, c 2 3, d e f, 4 5]
```

Comment: That is not the same as "split after every third whitespace" if the number of values is not a multiple of 3. E.g. input `"a b c d"` would split to `["a b c", "d"]` if you split on every 3rd space, but this code will return `["a b c"]` and **silently** discard the dangling `"d"`.

Comment: @Andreas You're right, but at least the OP seems to only want the triplet matches, and seems to discard the portions at the end which don't match.

Comment: Yes, but your answer should mention that "limitation" or quirk of this implementation.

Comment: @Andreas I "fixed" my answer (but just wait until the OP tells us it wanted the original version `:-)` )

Comment: *FYI:* My edit wasn't as much to specify languages, but more just to split the block with explanation and code in two. An empty comment (`<!-- -->`) would have done that. Specifying languages to control color-coding is just icing on the cake.

Comment: This answer totally works for me as I am actually trying to just split the first occurance and handle the rest later. Thank you!